# Pandas groupby then drop groups below specified size

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to separate a DataFrame into groups and drop groups below a minimum size (small outliers).

Here's what I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['A']).filter(lambda x: x.count() > min_size)
df.groupby(['A']).filter(lambda x: x.size() > min_size)
df.groupby(['A']).filter(lambda x: x['A'].count() > min_size)
df.groupby(['A']).filter(lambda x: x['A'].size() > min_size)
```

But these either throw an exception or return a different table than I'm expecting. I'd just like to filter, not compute a new table.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `len`:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that `filter` is actually returning the original DataFrame (not the grouped DataFrame). So the correct way to get the groups with size > N is `df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > N).groupby('A')`.

Answer (score 3):

`groupby.filter` can be very slow for larger dataset / a large number of groups. A faster approach is to use `groupby.transform`:

Here's an example, first create the dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'y': np.random.randn(np.random.randint(1,5))}).assign(A=str(i)) 
    for i in range(1,1000)
]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

```
             y    A
0     1.375980    1
1    -0.023861    1
2    -0.474707    1
3    -0.151859    2
4    -1.696823    2
...        ...  ...
2424  0.276737  998
2425 -0.142171  999
2426 -0.718891  999
2427 -0.621315  999
2428  1.335450  999

[2429 rows x 2 columns]
```

Time it:

[image: timing]

Comment: Not easily copy-pastable haha
df.loc[df.groupby("A")]["y"].transform("count") > 1,:]

Answer (score 2):

The number of rows is in the attribute `.shape[0]`:

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x.shape[0] >= min_size)
```

NB: If you want to remove the groups *below* the minimum size, keep those that are *above or at* the minimum size (`>=`, not `>`).