# Dataframe group by only groups with 2 or more rows

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

Is there a way to groupby only groups with 2 or more rows?

Or can I delete groups from a grouped dataframe that contains only 1 row?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584371/15415267

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Here is an example below

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([['A','A','B','C','C'],[1,2,1,1,2]]).T
    , columns= ['type','value']
    )
groups = df.groupby('type')
groups_without_single_row_df = [g for g in groups if len(g[1]) > 1]
```

`groupby` return a list of tuples.
Here, 'type' (A, b or C) is the first element of the tuple and the subdataframe the second element.

You can check length of each subdataframe with len() as in `[g for g in groups if len(g[1]) > 1]` where we check the lengh of the second element of the tuple.
If the the len() is greater than 1, it is include in the ouput list.

Hope it helps

---

### EDIT

The code above return a `dict` and not a group object. The link
[stackoverflow.com/a/54584371/15415267](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584371/15415267)
from Bushmaster provides a better way to reach the goal.

Here the improved code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([['A','A','B','C','C'],[1,2,1,1,2]]).T
    , columns= ['type','value']
)
groups = df.groupby('type').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1).groupby('type', group_keys= False)

groups.apply(lambda x: x*2)
```

Comment: It seems that this answer misses the last part: how to execute apply on the result ?

Comment: My mistake... The `groups_without_single_row_df ` return a dict so apply can't be used.
 I will updated the answer